# Alias of an object key using COSMOSDB sql query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am working with Cosmos DB and I want to write a SQL query that returns different name of an key in document object.

To elaborate, imagine you have the following document in one container having "makeName" key in "make" object.

```
{ 
   "vehicleDetailId":"38CBEAF7-5858-4EED-8978-E220D2BA745E",
   "type":"Vehicle",
   "vehicleDetail":{ 
      "make":{ 
         "Id":"B57ADAAD-C16E-44F9-A05B-AAB3BF7068B9",
         "makeName":"BMW"
      }
   }
}
```

I want to write a query to display "vehicleMake" key in place of "makeName".
How to give alias name in the nested object property.

Output should be like below

```
{ 
   "vehicleDetailId":"38CBEAF7-5858-4EED-8978-E220D2BA745E",
   "type":"Vehicle",
   "vehicleDetail":{ 
      "make":{ 
         "Id":"B57ADAAD-C16E-44F9-A05B-AAB3BF7068B9",
         "vehicleMake":"BMW"
      }
   }
}
```

I have no idea how to query in Cosmosdb to get the above result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.vehicleDetailId, c.type, 
{"make":{"Id":c.vehicleDetail.make.Id, "vehicleMake":c.vehicleDetail.make.makeName}} as vehicleDetail 
FROM c
```

It uses the aliasing described in the following documentation.  All of the aliasing examples I could find in the documentation or blog posts only show a single level of json output, but it happens that you can nest an object (make) within an object (vehichleDetail) to get the behavior you want.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-aliasing

Answer (score 3):

Aliases for properties are similar to the way you'd create a column alias in SQL Server, with the `as` keyword. In your example, it would be:

```sql
SELECT c.vehicleDetail.make.makeName as vehicleMake
FROM c
```

This would return:

```
[
  {
    "vehicleMake": "BMW"
  }
]
```

Comment: I need to display vehicleMake property in make object.
I tried the below query but didnt get the proper output as expected.

SELECT 
 c.vehicleDetailId
,c.type
,c.vehicleDetail
,c.vehicleDetail.make.Id as vehicleMake 
FROM c  

Any idea how to write the query to display the requested output

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392533/can-anyone-give-me-some-tips-or-suggestions-for-how-i-might-improve-this-questio